# My question was closed; where's a better place to ask it?

Tags: support

My [question about the origins of the berkeley socket API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950021/who-actually-invented-berkeley-sockets) was quickly closed by moderators as 'off-topic'.  It's a specific question about software engineering, so while I don't understand why that would be considered off-topic, can some one suggest a more suitable forum other than stack overflow?  It's not immediately obvious to me that there is one.

Comment: Your question was not closed by moderators but by community members. Stack Overflow is not a forum, btw.

Comment: Is this question yours too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951727/who-founded-berkeley-sockets

Comment: @Mat: No, it's not, that's so weird.  Somebody obviously wanted to know the answer and cut-and-pasted, but I swear it wasn't me, honest!

Comment: Out of interest, why is this question being downvoted? I mean, seriously?

Comment: [Voting works differently on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: (And Dan is much friendlier [than the author of that duplicate](http://i.stack.imgur.com/l44BL.png), @Mat `;-)`)

Answer (score 11):

Check the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) for what is on topic on Stack Overflow. Let's see how your question fits:

> - a specific programming problem

You don't have a programming problem.

> - a software algorithm

Nope.

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

No tool involved.

> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

Again, you don't have a programming problem there.

So your question doesn't really fit on Stack Overflow.

---

There are a few open questions about the history of various computing terms/language features and such over at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) (I'm not active on that site, so take this advice with a grain of salt).
I think you could also try it on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com), which has some  questions and answers about the history of Unix and Unix-like systems, tools and terms.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have enough reputation to view your original post, but I suspect that you didn't really have a question about the practice of software engineering. Based on the word "origins," I think you had a question about history that happened to relate to software engineering.

There is currently no site on the SE network where such a question would be on-topic. (Side note: some people around here can get kind of prickly when you refer to SO or other SE sites as "forums.") If you were looking for a non-SE site to ask on, I don't know of one (and that would make your question off-topic for *this* site).

You could also try asking in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com), where the rules about being on-topic and constructive are much less strict. There probably isn't a room devoted to the topic of Berkeley sockets, but there are some pretty well-rounded people in the more active rooms who might just happen to know the answer you're looking for, or at least be able to point you in a good direction.

Comment: The question title was *Who actually invented Berkeley sockets?*. The body of the question just added a small amount of background detail to the titular question, so you're not missing much.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably ask such a history question in a Unix/BSD/etc like mailing group or Usenet group. http://gmane.org/ is a great place to find mailing lists. Most are quite strict about on topic questions, but some, and some Usenet groups, are specifically dedicated to a broader range of discourse and people filter accordingly. They aren't a perfect substitute for Stack Overflow of course, but serve well in their niche.